# Fix invisible cursor?

Tags: cursor

Is there a fix for this bug that causes my cursor to randomly disappear? It happens every couple minutes and it's incredibly frustrating because I'm constantly trying to figure out where my cursor is.

I'm running High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G3025) on a 15 inch 2015 Macbook pro with two external monitors.

Some additional details:

The cursor stays invisible until I right click or press cmd-tab. It seems to happen with several apps including Chrome and Atom, but I've noticed it happens quite a bit more frequently when I mouse over a [kitty terminal](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/#) window.

Comment: Cursor as pointer or is it build in or BT or USB

Comment: Mouse cursor. I'm using the macbook's built-in touchpad.

Comment: Just to be clear this is not the normal disappearance of the cursor when you are typing text into a web form, or other document? As all I have to do to get the cursor back is to touch the trackpad and voila!

Comment: we can not help you without more details from you ! Cursor where in what App ?

Comment: Added some extra details to the question

Comment: Thank you for that, however I think you are talking about vanishing Mouse Pointer, not a Text cursor, that only shows in text input windows.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Right. Sorry I didn't realize there was a difference between "cursor" and "pointer". It's the mouse pointer that is disappearing.

Comment: I thought so :) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mouse cursor has mysteriously disappeared in OS X, try the following tricks in descending order to bring it back:

1. Hit Command+Tab to switch back to the Finder or to another app, then switch back to the active app
2. Summon the Force Quit menu by hitting Command+Option+Escape, there is often no need to actually force quit anything as just summoning the menu is often enough to make the cursor return
3. Quit and relaunch the app, or quit all apps if the cursor is gone everywhere
4. Adjust the size of the cursor, found in System Preferences > Accessibility > Display to make it reappear

Reboot

Let me know if problem remains.

Comment: Slightly increasing the cursor size in system preferences seems to have fixed the issue entirely.

Comment: totally doesn't fix mine. the only thing that brings mine back is clicking the top menu somewhere, generally the apple icon in the top left. super annoying when you're playing a videogame and your cursor disappears.

Comment: This is not a fix.  A fix would be something along the lines of upgrade to version x and the problem goes away, or change this config file and the problem goes away.  Also, having to close your apps and reboot constantly is not a fix either.  Apple needs to come up with an update for this.  It gets really annoying!