# Mouse cursor really frequently vanishes

Tags: macos, mojave

Recently my mouse cursor is disappearing *a lot* and I can't make it visible again until I slide where the mouse should be up to the menu bar and click the menu bar.

How do I fix this?

Some people think this is same question as: [Fix invisible cursor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342793/fix-invisible-cursor)

Maybe it is? But that's for an older OS, and the OP of that question has accepted an answer that doesn't fix the problem for me.

I want to *prevent*  the problem from happening at all ("fix").

I have already detailed how I can get my cursor back when it disappears, but it's really annoying and I want that to not happen.

The other question some people flagged as duplicate doesn't help out at all.

Comment: If you shake your mouse, does the cursor become bigger allowing you to see it ? I lose my cursor all the time and that action helps me a lot !

Comment: @EddGrowl I am not losing it, it literally becomes invisible.

Comment: yes that is what I meant, sorry for the confusion. Sometime when I use the full screen mode on an app my cursor vanish and doesn't come back until I shake my mouse. I was wondering if it was the same issue here.

Comment: @EddGrowl doesn't seem to work for me. Only clicking on the menu bar or revealing Mission Control shows the mouse again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix invisible cursor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342793/fix-invisible-cursor)

Comment: Same problem. I've tried all the stuff and it disappears constantly. Its the worst when you're playing a videogame, like league of legends, and it disappears bc you cant exactly tab away and not die. Is there a place to check for an error code? Or do we have some way of checking whether this is a bug or is instead considered a feature?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a someone had this issue as well and accept the answer here : [Fix invisible cursor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342793/fix-invisible-cursor) :

> If your mouse cursor has mysteriously disappeared in OS X, try the
>   following tricks in descending order to bring it back:
>
> 1. Hit Command+Tab to switch back to the Finder or to another app, then switch back to the active app
> 2. Summon the Force Quit menu by hitting Command+Option+Escape, there is often no need to actually force quit anything as just summoning the
>      menu is often enough to make the cursor return
> 3. Quit and relaunch the app, or quit all apps if the cursor is gone everywhere
> 4. Adjust the size of the cursor, found in System Preferences > Accessibility > Display to make it reappear
>
> Reboot

Also, he commented that :

> Slightly increasing the cursor size in system preferences seems to have fixed the issue entirely.

Comment: "Slightly increasing the cursor size in system preferences seems to have fixed the issue entirely." didn't work. The rest of this answer is not a solution.

Comment: Don't copy an answer from another question. If the answer is the same then you shpould flag the question as a duplicate so any new readers will see a pointer to the actual answers

Comment: Some other people claim they fixed the issue with an NVRAM reset ( described here : https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT204063 )